# Correct approach for getting the values from tables

Tags: oracle

I am trying to fetch the records from table. 
My table structure is as below and 'id' is the primarykey

```
| id | location| parent_id |
|----|---------|-----------|
| 1  | abc     | NULL      |
| 2  | xyz     | 1         | 
| 3  | def     | 2         |
```

I am trying to get the id ,name, parent_id and parent_name.
I am using the below join query to get the result and it works fine. 
I just wanted a opinion , is there any better way to get the results.

I have used a join query to get the results.

```
SELECT location1.id as childid,
location1.location as childlocation ,
locationparent.id as parentid,
locationparent.location as parentlocation  
FROM location  location1
JOIN location  locationparent 
ON location1.parent_id = locationparent.id  
WHERE location1.id =2  ;
```

Comment: If its just a single level, then the join should be fine. If you need to traverse the hierarchy, ie 3 reports to 2 who reports to 1, then check out CONNECT BY syntax

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how this might be achieved with a hierarchical query (using CONNECT BY).  I added a few more sample data rows to better demonstrate the concept.

```
SQL> WITH location_tbl (id, location, parent_id) AS (
  2    SELECT 1, 'abc', NULL from dual UNION ALL
  3    SELECT 2, 'xyz', 1 from dual UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 3, 'def', 2 from dual UNION ALL
  5    SELECT 4, 'ggg', 2 from dual UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 5, 'hhh', 3 from dual UNION ALL
  7    SELECT 6, 'iii', 3 from dual
  8  )
  9  SELECT id, location, parent_id, PRIOR location parent_location
 10    FROM location_tbl
 11    CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
 12    START WITH id = 1;

        ID LOCATION  PARENT_ID PARENT_LOCATION
---------- -------- ---------- ---------------
         1 abc                                
         2 xyz               1 abc            
         3 def               2 xyz            
         5 hhh               3 def            
         6 iii               3 def            
         4 ggg               2 xyz
```